# need regex to extract two substrings from one string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string similar to `tvm11551.iso` that I am trying to parse. In this string, these bolded numbers vary: tvm **11** 5 **51** .iso (please ignore the spaces here). I wrote the following program in PHP that would extract those two numbers from that string:

```
$a = "tvm11551.iso";

if(preg_match('/^tvm\d{5}\.iso/',$a)){
    $b = preg_match('/tvm(\d\d)\d\d\d\.iso/' , $a);
    $c = preg_match('/tvm\d\d\d(\d\d)\.iso/' , $a);
    echo "B: " . $b . "<br>";
    echo "C: " . $c;
}
```

However, I am getting the output as:

```
B: 1
C: 1
```

How do I fix the RegEx to get the expected output?

Comment: Is it _always_ two digits on each side of the `5`, and 5 digits in total?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `1` you are seeing as output is the number of matches, not their contents, that `preg_match()` returns on a successful match. Since each of your tests had only one `()` capture group, one match was returned. You need to capture matches into an array as the third argument to `preg_match()`:

```
$a = "tvm11551.iso";
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^tvm(\d{2})5(\d{2})\.iso$/', $a, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(12) "tvm11551.iso"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "11"
  [2] =>
  string(2) "51"
}
```

Comment: A better answer to the actual question asked (+1), but it's still pointless to be using RegEx here when a simple substring will do the job.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! Thats was easy! I later realized what a stupid question I asked, lol.

Comment: @Michael Just a small hint: the output `1` is an actual one, no `true`, since `preg_match()` returns the number of matches. `preg_match()` only searches for the first match and stops, so the return value is either `1` or `0`. [docs, see "Return Values"](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the patterns you have, I don't see any reason to be using RegEx at all, after the initial match.

You would just want this:

```
if(preg_match('/^tvm\d{5}\.iso/',$a)){
    $b = substr($a, 3, 5);
    $c = substr($a, 6, 8);
```

Comment: The main overhead is in loading the regex engine, so if you have already done so to match the filename, it probably won't hurt to just do the captures in the regex at this point. I'd be interested to see the benchmark to know if it is faster to switch into two `substr()` function calls after already initializing the regex...

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that about the overhead. I'd be interested in the benchmark too.

Answer (score 1):

preg_match returns the number of times the pattern matched (but since preg_match always stops at the first match it finds, it always returns 0 or 1). if you want to get the numbers that got matched, you haves to pass an array as the third parameter for preg_match. see [preg_match documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)